# get_template_part in for loop

Tags: wp-query, loop, get-posts

Due to the setup of my template (and layout), I need to be able to place 4 different posts in 4 different divs.

For example, my structure would be like this

```
<div>Post 1</div>
<div>
    <div>Post 2</div>
    <div>
        <div>Post 3</div>
        <div>Post 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I'm having some trouble getting this to work, I use `get_posts` to get the 4 latest posts.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_count' => 4
));
```

And then I try to display my post

```
<?php setup_postdata($posts[0]); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

In `template-parts/post-thumbnail.php` I'm trying to display the title and permalink, but it's always showing the title and link of the current page. Never of the actual post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that the variable passed to `setup_postdata()` *must* be the global `$post` variable, like this:

```
// Reference global $post variable.
global $post;

// Get posts.
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_count' => 4
));  

// Set global post variable to first post.
$post = $posts[0];

// Setup post data.
setup_postdata( $post );

// Output template part.
get_template_part( 'template-parts/post-thumbnail' );

// Reset post data.
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Now normal template functions, like `the_post_thumbnail()` inside the template part will reference the correct post.

Comment: Aha, that as it. I didn't realise it had to be specifically called `$post`, thanks!

Comment: Yeah it's pretty weird. I've definitely tripped over this many times before. Also make sure to use `global $post` so that you're using the global post variable.

Answer (score 4):

Other than messing with the globals, you can write a custom loop that requires absolutely no extra work to make your template part work. For example:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 4
);

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($my_query->have_posts()){
    while ($my_query->have_posts()){
        $my_query->the_post(); // This is where the post's data is set up
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/post-thumbnail' );
    }
}
```

Done. You don't need to set up post's data for each post in the loop.

By the way [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) itself uses a `WP_Query()` to fetch the posts, but the difference is that it doesn't set up the post's data for you, and it needs to be reset after the loop.

Comment: Sure, but due to my structure, I couldn't do this. Unless you can point me in the right direction to get it to work with that.

Comment: @woutr_be you can do the same thing by replacing `get_posts` with `$query = new WP_Query($args)` and replacing `setup_postdata()` with `$query->the_post()`. The `while` loop isn't strictly necessary, each call to `$query->the_post()` will populate the internal vars with the next post's data.

Answer (score 3):

$posts wouldn't be available within context of post-thumbnail.php if you're using [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/), so it will use the post ID found for the current page.  You should use [locate_template()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/) to make the variable available, which is what get_template_part uses internally, like this:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_count' => 4 ) ); ?>

<?php foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <?php locate_template( 'page-templates/post-thumbnail.php', true, false ); ?>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Then you would be able to have whatever you have in the page-templates/post-thumbnail.php template with the correct post data:

```
<div>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: locate_template isn't necessary. Template tags and the global post variable will be available in the template part if `setup_postdata()` is used correctly. OP's problem is that the variable passed to `setup_postdata()` *must* be called `$post`.

Comment: Interesting - I seem to recall having issues with get_template_part in the past, I just tested out your example and it works great, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Take it to your provinces

```
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

[`wp_reset_postdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) is important to reset a current query's result.